# Write a zoo object without the index

Tags: r, zoo

I have a zoo object (tmp) which has date and time as index and a value like below

```
> library(zoo)
> library(chron)
> tmp
(01/01/97 00:00:00) (01/01/97 01:00:00) (01/01/97 02:00:00) 
            5.0                 3.2                 6.7 
> dput(tmp)
structure(c(5, 3.2, 6.7), index = structure(c(9862, 9862.04166666667, 
9862.08333333333), format = structure(c("m/d/y", "h:m:s"), .Names = c("dates", 
"times")), origin = structure(c(1, 1, 1970), .Names = c("month", 
"day", "year")), class = c("chron", "dates", "times")), class = "zoo")
```

I am trying to write this zoo object to a text file and I just want the values written in the text file. I used the following code:

```
write.zoo(tmp,file="D:/test.txt", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, na="")
```

and I get the following file:

```
(01/01/97 00:00:00) 5
(01/01/97 01:00:00) 3.2
(01/01/97 02:00:00) 6.7
```

but the output I want is

```
5
3.2
6.7
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this?

Comment: Sorry for the correction, the zoo object looks likes this:

    > head(tmp)
             V1 V2 V3
    1  1/1/1997  0  5
    2  1/1/1997  1 3.2
    3  1/1/1997  2 6.7

Thank you
uvozone

Comment: It does not look like `tmp` is a zoo object.  Provie the output of `dput(tmp)`, and please edit your question with your correction, rather than via a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the data to a normal vector first, and write that as a normal table:

```
write.table(as.vector(tmp), file="D:/test.txt",
            row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, na="")
```

Actually the conversion to a vector appears to be unneccessary, but I consider it clearer as you indicate that you are throwing away the extra data zoo associates with these values.

As Joshua Ulrich write in a comment below, in case your `tmp` object has more than one column, you should probably use `coredata` instead of `as.vector`:

```
write.table(coredata(tmp), file="D:/test.txt",
            row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, na="")
```

The difference is that this will generate a file with multiple columns, whereas `as.vector` will generate a single column by simply writing out column vectors one after the other. Depends on your use case.

I guess (though I might be wrong) that the following works like the `coredata` version:

```
write.table(tmp, file="D:/test.txt",
            row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, na="")
```

Comment: Use `coredata` instead of `as.vector` because `as.vector` won't do what you want if `tmp` has dims.

Comment: Hi Joshua, can you give an example of how to use the coredata ? thank you - Nevermind I got it. just searched for coredata and found it in the zoo quickref. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich, thanks, incorporated that suggestion in my answer.